# Add one week to Date()

Tags: php

How do I add 1 week to a date function with separate date variables. The date needs to be separate so I can insert it into another form. If I cant do it as separate variables can i separate them afterwards?

So:

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$day = date("d");
echo 'Current Date' . $year . '.' . $month . '.' . $day;
echo 'Date 1 Week in the Future';
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
echo "Date 1 Week in the Future " . date('Y.m.d', strtotime('+1 Week'));
// Outputs: Date 1 Week in the Future 2012.03.10
```

To break up into separate variables (as per your comment):

```
$oneWeekLater = strtotime('+1 Week');

$year = date('Y', $oneWeekLater);
$month = date('m', $oneWeekLater);
$day = date('d', $oneWeekLater);

echo 'Date 1 Week in the Future' . $year . '.' . $month . '.' . $day;
```

Comment: @JohnAyers Updated my answer. Rename the date variables if you want to use the current date as well.

Comment: appreciate the help! Didn't realize you could just added it in with date like that.

Answer (score 7):

PHP offers the convenient [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) method for that:

```
$oneWeekLater = date('Y.m.d', strtotime('+1 week'));
```

To pass a custom date, use `strtotime`'s second parameter.

Comment: Seems like an exact copy of the previous answer which was posted 1 minute before yours...

Comment: @Tim: 38 seconds, actually, in 2012 when new answers weren’t loaded with websockets. I guess what I’m saying is that I didn’t copy the answer and if you’re not suggesting that then I don’t know what the point of your comment was.

Comment: @Tim: If you’re referring to the use of `$oneWeekLater` in both answers (the non-bog-standard part), note that the other answerer edited it in relatively long afterwards and probably “copied” it from me (but I don’t care, because it’s a variable name).

Comment: Initially just looked like a copy paste. Please accept my apology